# Failure attempting to generate a web map (any format) with Delimited Text Layer

Tags: qgis, csv, qgis2web

I have a delimited text layer I'd like to be able to export to a web map.  The vector base maps alone export as expected but the data layer refuses with errors.

There are 9 fields per row, a mix of double, int, and QString; 550 rows (or so) of data.  The Qstring format is UTF8, two fields have positive and negative numbers.  The symbol format uses a graduated color ramp driven by a double that ranges from -1 to 1 and the symbol size is in map units which are lat/lon.

Errors with Leaflet:

```
      File "/home/gessel/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/leafletWriter.py", line 90, in write
      self.preview_file = self.writeLeaflet(
      File "/home/gessel/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/leafletWriter.py", line 261, in writeLeaflet
      useOSMB) = writeVectorLayer(layer, safeLayerName,
      File "/home/gessel/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/leafletLayerScripts.py", line 128, in writeVectorLayer
      (legend, symbol) = getLegend(layer, renderer, outputProjectFileName,
      File "/home/gessel/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/leafletLayerScripts.py", line 365, in getLegend
      legend = iconLegend(symbol, c, outputProjectFileName,
      File "/home/gessel/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/leafletScriptStrings.py", line 239, in iconLegend
      QSize(iconSize,
     TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
      QSize(): too many arguments
      QSize(int, int): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
      QSize(QSize): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
```

Errors with OpenLayers

```
         2022-10-25T13:06:07     WARNING    warning:/home/gessel/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/olwriter.py:380: DeprecationWarning: QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.toProj4() is deprecated
          defn=mapSettings.destinationCrs().toProj4())
         
         traceback: File "/home/gessel/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/maindialog.py", line 337, in previewMap
          preview_file = self.createPreview()
          File "/home/gessel/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/maindialog.py", line 299, in createPreview
          return writer.write(self.iface,
          File "/home/gessel/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/olwriter.py", line 81, in write
          self.preview_file = self.writeOL(iface, feedback,
          File "/home/gessel/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/olwriter.py", line 159, in writeOL
          (proj, proj4, view) = getCRSView(mapextent, fullextent, maxZoom,
          File "/home/gessel/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/olwriter.py", line 380, in getCRSView
          defn=mapSettings.destinationCrs().toProj4())
```

errors with Mapbox

```
2022-10-25T13:07:23     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/home/gessel/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/maindialog.py", line 337, in previewMap
              preview_file = self.createPreview()
              File "/home/gessel/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/maindialog.py", line 299, in createPreview
              return writer.write(self.iface,
              File "/home/gessel/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/mapboxWriter.py", line 94, in write
              self.preview_file = self.writeMapbox(
              File "/home/gessel/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/mapboxWriter.py", line 283, in writeMapbox
              popups) = writeVectorLayer(layer, safeLayerName,
              File "/home/gessel/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/mapboxLayerScripts.py", line 147, in writeVectorLayer
              (legend, symbol) = getLegend(layer, renderer, outputProjectFileName,
              File "/home/gessel/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/mapboxLayerScripts.py", line 394, in getLegend
              legend = iconLegend(symbol, c, outputProjectFileName,
              File "/home/gessel/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/mapboxScriptStrings.py", line 227, in iconLegend
              QSize(iconSize,
             TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
              QSize(): too many arguments
              QSize(int, int): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
              QSize(QSize): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
```

Mod: Here's an excerpt from the data:

```
lat lon Cats Seen   New Cats    New to Old  Main City   Cats in City    Main Breed  count by breed
48.55   22.35   585 41  0.0701  Uzhhorod. Ukraine   576 Ryrpgeba-Freivpr YGQ    15
51.15   22.55   1219    73  0.0599  Lublin. Poland  1219    CR Vinabi Ivgnyvl Fretrrivpu    73
48.15   22.65   36  6   0.1667  Berehove. Ukraine   36  GryrEnqvbPbzcnal Fghqvb GI-4 Orertfnfbz Ygq.    3
48.35   22.75   107 13  0.1215  Mukacheve. Ukraine  107 CebXX FR    5
48.05   23.05   220 34  0.1545  Vynohradiv. Ukraine 220 Arj Vasbezngvba Flfgrzf CC  15
48.25   23.05   92  8   0.087   Irshava. Ukraine    92  SBC Zngvfulargf Freuvv  4
48.15   23.15   4   1   0.25    Rokosovo. Ukraine   4   Arj Vasbezngvba Flfgrzf CC  1
49.45   23.15   74  5   0.0676  Sambir. Ukraine 74  Fgngr Ragrecevfr Fpvragvsvp naq Gryrpbzzhavpngvba Prager Hxenvavna Npnqrzvp naq Erfrnepu Argj   4
47.95   23.35   12  1   0.0833  Shaian. Ukraine 12  SBC Ovuhargf Vfugina Fgrcnabilpu    1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I try to export a very minimal example map with the following as a UTF8 encoded text file added as a layer it works.

```
name;lat;lon;float_number;int_number;
first;52.0;9.0;-1;98
second;53.0;9.5;-0.8;11
third;53.2;9.6;0.42;912
förth;51.2;8.916;1.0;36
```

You should try to gradually rebuild your project, and try exporting after each step, so that you can see where exactly the error occurs.

Also, check if the plugin is at its latest version, and try reinstalling the plugin.

edit:
This is my styling. Exports good.

[image: styling and map display]

edit2: Yes, different symbol (cross) is not rendered correctly in leaflet:

[image: symbol cross mangled in preview]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 

QGIS is 3.28.0, qgis2web is 3.16.0.  So far (restart qgis between each test):

* 9 lines as above without styling: completes - webmap shows.  YAY!
* 9 lines with "complicated" styling - webmap never completes.  Boo.
* 550 lines without styling, oh - hey that works!
* 550 lines with styling... well no.  

However the errors are probably a red herring, they show even when the process completes.  I'm going to dig into the symbol styling and labels as that seems to be the problem.

Comment: Ah, the problem seems to be symbols->graduated->color/color-ramp/New to Old as the value.  I set a fixed interval of 0.1 for 20 intervals and it never renders.  Same with 2 intervals and with size as a method.  Switching to "rule based" didn't seem to help.  

It is highly desirable to have the symbols coded by value (color preferred).  Perhaps that's not possible with a web map?

Comment: could you try changing the symbol size units to either "Map Units" or "Meters at Scale" Also to a shape other than circle.  If I set the shape of the "simple marker" to a square (desirable for my application) it renders in qgis but the web export is a dot.  The other issue is if I set the symbol size to map units or meters at scale, the results are odd: the basemap exports but starts blank, mousewheel zooming renders it.  The CSV data does not render. Open layers does yield colored, mm-sized round dots with pop-up data.  Leaflet and Mapbox are throwing errors.

Comment: Is this a "bug" or an unimplemented feature?  I'm happy to file a bug report or a feature request.  Given that it is an interaction with an external library, it may well be a limitation of that library.

Comment: There are some bug reports concerning symbology in qgis2web, for example https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/978 . If you find the time it would be a good thing to create a simple QGIS project exhibiting your problem and upload that as a bug report in the qgis2web github.

Comment: I'll do so.  Thank you very much for the help, very much appreciated.